# prove product sigma algebra contains all open sets

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove that $\mathcal{M} \times \mathcal{M}$ contains all open sets of $R^2$. I know that $\mathcal{M} \times \mathcal{M}$ is the product sigma algebra generated by the measurable rectangles of $\mathcal{M}$, but I'm not certain if each open subset of $R^2$ is a countable union of measurable rectangles.

Please help me with the proof of this fact. Thanks.

Comment: How do you define an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$? The usual "open ball around points contained in the set"-thing?

Comment: The standard argument would use "dyadic" squares.  You divide the plane into squares of length $1/2^n$ and take those which are contained in your open set.  Do this for each $n$ and union them all.

Comment: This is basically showing that the product of Borel sigma algebras on separable metric spaces is the Borel sigma algebra on the product space. You can see Prop. 1.4 and 1.5 in Folland's Real Analysis for a proof.

Comment: @HowDoIMath. Yes, that's how I define it.

Answer (score 1):

Let consider the family $\cal{A}$ of sets of the form $(a,b)\times (c,d)$, where $a,b,c,d$ are rational numbers. This family is countable and it is contained in $\cal{M} \times \cal{M}$. Each open set $G$ in $R^2$ is presented as the union of a countable family of elements of $\cal{A}$. This means that the  family $\cal{G}$ of all open sets in $R^2$ is subset of $\sigma(\cal{A})$, where $\sigma(\cal{A})$ denotes the minimal $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $R^2$ generated by the family  $\cal{A}$. On the other hand,  $\sigma(\cal{A})=\cal{M} \times \cal{M}$, which implies that  $\cal{G} \subset \cal{M} \times \cal{M}$.

Comment: Each open set in $R^2$ is a countable union of sets in $\mathcal{A}$, can you elaborate? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: Let $G\subseteq R^2$ be an open set. For  $x \in G$ there is  $(a_x,b_x)\times (c_x,d_x) \in \cal{A}$ such that  $x \in  (a_x,b_x)\times (c_x,d_x)$ and  $ (a_x,b_x)\times (c_x,d_x)\subseteq G$. It is obvious that  $G=\cup_{x \in  G} (a_x,b_x)\times (c_x,d_x)$.  But  $\{(a_x,b_x)\times (c_x,d_x) : x \in G\}\subseteq \cal{A}$  which means that the family   $\{(a_x,b_x)\times (c_x,d_x) : x \in G\}$ is countable.